# Remote debugging python with pycharm from windows host to windows guest

Tags: python, virtual-machine, remote-debugging, pycharm, python-2.4

I have to work on this really horrible old python project which only runs in a windows xp VM. Is there a way to use pycharm in the host and connect to the interpreter in the guest (which is python 2.4 by the way).

I have used vagrant before with a linux guest but never tried it with a windows guest and can't seem to find any information about it.

I'm guessing I need to install sshd on the guest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here is a video which explains the pycharm remote-debugging](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0Gxxjbos4k) from linux-mint host to ubuntu server. Explanations are Turkish but you can still understand the steps by watching the video.

I also did lots of search about remote-debugging on pycharm. This video was one of the best. Good luck....

Comment: The problem here is that the OP wants to run against a Windows remote and not Linux.  I tried this last night and it proved problematic, since the script that sets up the remote environment is trying to run the 'env' command which doesn't work in Windows.  I put in a ticket with JetBrains - hopefully there is a way to do this.

As for Vagrant, it is possible to use it with Windows, but it really is intended for use with Linux. You can find windows boxes on the hashicorp atlas, but unless you have a big project with many developers, I'd just make a plain ol windows VM.